# How to do minibatch evaluation using CNTK eval api

Tags: cntk

I want to use CNTK Evaluation API to give scores for my data. Currently I see there is one by one way of evaluation. I am curious whether the minibatch  supported in CNTK evaluation? Where could I find some sample code for it?

Answer (score 3):

Evaluation with batch data is supported by the new version of C# Eval API. [This page](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Library-Evaluation-on-Windows#using-the-cntk-library-managed-api) describes how to use the API. And you can find [examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Examples/Evaluation) here with [building instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Eval-Examples).

Comment: need this in python api asap!  Trainer.eval_minibatch(batch) but no model.eval_minibatch(batch) ... so silly

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted long ago but in case someone else ends on this question.

In python there is a direct parallel between using a minibatch in training and evaluation. In training, the `.train_minibatch` method can be used on a `cntk.Trainer` object and for evaluation the `.test_minibatch` method can be used on a `cntk.Evaluator` object.

See the section "3. Feeding Data Via an Explicit Minibatch Loop" in [CNTK_200_GuidedTour](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/CNTK_200_GuidedTour.html?highlight=ctfdeserializer) for an example.